# Are salted passwords obsolete?

Tags: security

I heard that nobody uses Rainbow tables these days, instead they use GPUs, so you should rely on computationally expensive hash function. Is it true?

Comment: That's like asking if you should enable password recover by Rainbow table. If anyone were to find out that you don't salt your passwords (which they could find out easily by using a Rainbow tale to check a few) they could easily reverse many of the password hashes.

Comment: salting is the prime countermeasure vs rainbow tables

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rainbow tables became less of a viable attack vector *because* properly designed systems began salting passwords. Using a computationally expensive hash is a good counter measure to other kinds of attacks but does not mean that salted passwords are obsolete.